# How do create progress bar while clicking remove button in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I have created exe file using nsis script.In my script i have included Repair Remove features.

If the user select remove option it will remove the application.Its working.I have used following code for remove

```
    Function nsDialogpage
    ${If} $Remove == 1
      call Removed
     ${EndIf}
    FunctionEnd

Function Removed
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
FunctionEnd
```

After installed application clicking uninstal.exe it show progress bar and list of files.finally it removed the application from system.
I want to run the scenario while clicking remove button.but in the above code remove the application only.It doesnot show any details.

How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using nsExec?

Answer (score 0):

The uninstall output list is controlled by `ShowUninstDetails` (compile time) and `SetDetailsView` (run time).

Comment: where am give this command? while removing? can you explain more?